# click links though javascript

Tags: javascript

Am looking for how to click links on my page using javascript. In my page i show each record from my database . and a 'show' link to the right clicking it will expand and display the row in detail. i want to expand all the rows at once . Is it possible to click link in Javascript like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cycle through all of the anchors, and click them, yes:

```
var myLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < myLinks.length; i++) {
  myLinks[i].click();
}
```

Note that this will click *every* link on the page. You can focus more on a specific set of links by going through a parent container that sits just outside of them:

```
var myLinks = document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("a");
```

This would get all links within the element having the `id` value of "container".

**Update2:**

Within the comments, you wanted to know how to click only links whose `ID` begins with a specific string. Let's look at a couple ways we can implement that into our aforementioned code:

Using jQuery, you could click all `id='reviews-show...'` links like this:

```
$("a[id^='reviews-show']").click(); // simple, eh?
```

The `^=` in this selector matches in a regular-expression style, asking if the string *starts* with "reviews-show," which will retrieve only the `a` tags for which this statement is true.

If you want to stick with just regular javascript, we can modifiy our first code-block to check the substring:

```
var myLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < myLinks.length; i++) {
  currentlink = myLinks[i];
  if (currentlink.id.substring(0,12) === "reviews-show") {
    currentlink.click();
  }
}
```

**Update:**

Apparently [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is rotting my mind, and my solution doesn't work as-is. If you don't mind using jQuery (you'd love it), you could go this route:

```
$("a").click();           //clicks all links on page
$("#container a").click();//clicks all links within element having id 'container'
```

If you want to stay away from a framework, try adding this prototype extension into the top of your code which will make my original answer sufficient:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.click = function() {
  if (document.createEvent) {
    var evt = this.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, this.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
  } else if (this.fireEvent) {
    this.fireEvent("onclick");
  }
}
```

Source: http://www.barattalo.it/2009/11/18/click-links-with-javascript/

Comment: i have another doubt. i have to only select links with id like "reviews-show-15498-link"
"reviews-show-15499-link"

is it possible to select ids starting with "reviews-show"

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet does not require jQuery:

```
<script>
    const dumpToggleLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('sf-dump-toggle');
    for (let i = 1; i < dumpToggleLinks.length; i++) {
        dumpToggleLinks[i].click();
    }
</script>
```